# How can I go out from the cycle

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
while (true)
            {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int h = ok_group_join(gr);
                        if (h == 0)
                            ok_group_post(gr);
                        else if (h == -1)
                        {
                          //How can I go to first while cycle?
                        }
```

I wrote a comment in my code, how can I return from there to first while cycle?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Adding a `break` should break you out of the inner while and continue the outer while.

Comment: Look up how to use a break;

Comment: Use `goto` *duck down* ... no, do not. Goto have it's uses in `C` but there is no need in well written C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true)
            {
                string acc = "";
                lock (accslocker)
                {
                    if (accs.Count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        acc = accs.Dequeue();
                }
                string cook = od_auth(acc);
                if (cook != "badacc")
                {
                    string gr;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int h = ok_group_join(gr);
                        if (h == 0)
                            ok_group_post(gr);
                        else if (h == -1)
                        {
                          //How can I go to first while cycle?
                          break;
                        }
```

The `break` keyword will let you out.

Answer (score 1):

use [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
else if (h == -1)
{
    break;
}
```

This will break you out of the current while loop causing you to fall back into the previous while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than using a `break` is re-write the inner loop to not be a `while (true)`.

```
while (true)
{
    int h = 0;
    while (h != -1)
    {
        h = ok_group_join(gr);
        if (h == 0)
            ok_group_post(gr);
    }
 }
```